# Looking for an USB "swiss army knife"

Tags: usb, development, cable

In my job, I need to interact with a lot of different systems and a lot of different USB ports.

I'm looking for a single USB tool that would guaranty that I would be able to connect two USB ports together, no matter their types or if they're male or female.

Those kinds of USB multi-tools already exist but for **power only** cables (useful for charging your phone).
[image]

Any idea where I could find something similar, but with data support?

Comment: You might want to consider finding a bunch of individual adapters that have Micro B female and various other device connectors on the other end. In most cases those kinds of adapters support data transfer too. Then you just use a typical A to Micro B cable with whatever adapter you need on the end. (This would be easier to replace any individual piece if they're missing or broken. Instead of replacing the whole thing)

Comment: I've bad experience with those kind of devices, they tend to be very cheap and break down easily.

Comment: Cool as an idea as this is, you'd need some significant circuitry to handle connection selection. AFAIK no such *commercial* device exists. One alternative is to just use a simple C <-> C cable with adapters on each end. Besides A, B, C, Micro, and Mini, are there any other USB-ish connections you need? Is USB 3 important?